# TextBlock не отзывается на INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

Поиск в интернетах не дал результатов, у многих есть такая же проблема. Использовать вместо `TextBlock` `TextBox`, не могу, нужны `Run'ы`

Описал в VM интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Опракидываю всякий раз когда меняется поле. В `xaml` сделал `TextBlock`, который должен всякий раз обновлять текст внутри себя. Привязка на `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` не работает. Может повесить какие триггеры?

VM:

```
public string BasePart
{
    get { return m_basePart;}
    set {
        if (m_basePart != value)
        {
            m_basePart = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("BasePart");
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:-

```
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" 
                   Text="{Binding BasePart, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вношу изменения в `BasePart`, выше есть описание как работает `BasePart`

```
        <TextBox Text="{Binding BasePart, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
             Height="20"
             Width="200"/>
```

Comment: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` ... да не TextBlock...было бы смешно, если бы не было так грустно. Посмотрите, например, в Snoop есть ли ошибки привязки? `DataContext` нормально установлен?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper на окне у меня стоит эвент Loaded где я кладу в datacontext свою VM. у строки которую я кладу в TextBlock есть стандартный текст, он туда кладется...

Comment: @Ev_Hyper Прошелся снупом, у TextBox например Text : {Path=StringValueText} Local. А у TextBlock Text : мой текст Local. Ошибка, Расширил строчку, путь есть на биндинг, и он правильный

Comment: скриншот со снупом можете добавить в вопрос?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper добавил

Comment: Хорошо, а теперь еще раз напишите в чем проблема. Так как в том коде что вы привели по всей видимости ошибок нет.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper у меня есть TextBlock, на его пропертю Text я вешаю Binding с UpdateSourceTrigger. В VM описал интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged, По итогу textblock не подхватыет изменение

Comment: покажите как вы вносите изменения в `BasePart`

Comment: @Ev_Hyper добавил в вопрос

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, Я правильно понял, что вы биндите `TextBlock` и `TextBox` к одному свойству, но при изменении свойства через текстовое поле `TextBlock` не меняет старое значение на новое?

Comment: @maxwell именно!

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, Ваш код должен работать в этом виде. Залейте проект куда-нибудь и скиньте ссылку.

Comment: @maxwell я решил проблему, создав банально partical class и переназначив DependencyProperty Text.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, Костыли вы мои, костыли :)